# Filttering and mapping in react native/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, filter, mapping

My question here is, how do I map the 'products' object based on the tab  I choose in the Products component? Example: In the Products component, it renders 8 tabs for each type of food (dataSaleThumb), if I choose 1 tab (out of 8) that has the value `tab: "five"` I need to filter and map out all of the products that have the prop `category: "food"`. Or clicking on the tab that has the value `tab: "six"` maps out only the products that have the `category:"beverages"` prop. I hope you understood the question and I thank you all in advance!

```
class ProductsStore {
  @observable products = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'sandwich',
        description: 'tasty',
        price: 150,
        catergory: "food"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'fanta',
        description: 'orange drink',
        price: 250,
        catergory: "beverage"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'hamburger',
        description: 'meat',
        price: 350,
        catergory: "food"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'cola',
        description: 'caramel drink',
        price: 250,
        catergory: "beverage"
    }
];
}

export default ProductsStore;
```

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {View, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity,FlatList, Text} from "react-native";
import {Container, Content, List} from "native-base";
import {observer, inject} from "mobx-react";
import ThemeHeader from "../../components/Header/index.js";
import SaleThumb from "../../components/SaleThumb/index.js";
import SaleTitle from "../../components/SaleTitle/index.js";
import MyFooter from "../../components/Footer";
import styles from "./styles.js";

var deviceWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
var deviceHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;

@inject("products")
@observer
class Product extends Component {
  
  render() {
    const navigation = this.props.navigation;
    
    var dataSaleThumb = [
      {
        id: 1,
        imageSaleThumb: require("../../../assets/p1.jpg"),
        text: "ABCDFG",
        tab: "one"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        imageSaleThumb: require("../../../assets/p2.jpg"),
        text: "ABCDFG",
        tab: "two"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        imageSaleThumb: require("../../../assets/p3.jpg"),
        text: "ABCDFG",
        tab: "three"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        imageSaleThumb: require("../../../assets/p4.jpg"),
        text: "ABCDFG",
        tab: "four"
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        imageSaleThumb: require("../../../assets/p5.jpg"),
        text: "ABCDFG",
        tab: "five"
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        imageSaleThumb: require("../../../assets/p6.jpg"),
        text: "ABCDFG",
        tab: "six"
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        imageSaleThumb: require("../../../assets/p7.jpg"),
        text: "ABCDFG",
        tab: "seven"
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        imageSaleThumb: require("../../../assets/p8.jpg"),
        text: "ABCDFG",
        tab: "eight"
      }
    ];
    
    return (
      <Container>
        <ThemeHeader
          PageTitle="PRODUCT"
          IconLeft="ios-arrow-back"
          route="homepage"
          IconRight="ios-search"
          navigation={navigation}
        />
        <Content
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 10 }}
          style={{ marginBottom: 50 }}
        >
            <FlatList
              bounces={false}
              contentContainerStyle={styles.saleThumb}
              data={dataSaleThumb}
              renderItem={item => (
                <SaleThumb
                  navigation={navigation}
                  blockHeight={deviceHeight / 3 - 45}
                  blockWidth={deviceWidth / 3 - 10}
                  saleData={item.item.text}
                  imageSource={item.item.imageSaleThumb}
                />
              )}
            />
          </View>
        </Content>
        <MyFooter navigation={navigation} selected={"home"} />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default observer(Product);
```

Comment: You should add the category to the dataSaleThumb as there is no way to say "one" is "food", there should be a link between the two arrays to filter

Comment: @Guruparan Giritharan Thanks for the help but I'm still not able to do what I intended to...

Comment: Hey, your question should specify how to filter, which is not clear

Comment: @Guruparan Giritharan I thought I cleared it up in the first post, I need to filter out products from the MobX store into another component when I press a tab in the Product component, I need to filter only products with the specific category, like I said in the beginning, If I choose tab 5 I need to filter out the products with the category:beverages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, I found a solution with a little help from a cousin.

First we add the category props in the dataSaleThumb object in the Product screen:

```
var dataSaleThumb = [
      {
        id: 1,
        imageSaleThumb: require("../../../assets/p1.jpg"),
        text: "ABCDFG",
        tab: "one",
        category: "beverage"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        imageSaleThumb: require("../../../assets/p2.jpg"),
        text: "ABCDFG",
        tab: "two",
        category: "food"
      }
...
```

Then we declare an onPress function in the Product screen:

```
<FlatList
               bounces={false}
               contentContainerStyle={styles.saleThumb}
               data={dataSaleThumb}
               renderItem={item => (
                 <SaleThumb
       onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ProductCatalogue", {categoryId: categoryId})}
                   navigation={navigation}
                   blockHeight={deviceHeight / 3 - 45}
                   blockWidth={deviceWidth / 3 - 10}
                   saleData={item.item.text}
                   imageSource={item.item.imageSaleThumb}
                   categoryId={item.item.category}
                 />
               )}
             />
```

where ProductCatalogue (you can call it whatever you like) is the screen where the products with the specific category will render. After that in the ProductCatalogue screen you map the specific items with an IF statement like this:

```
renderItem={item => {
             if (item.item.category === navigation.getParam('categoryId')) {
               return(
                 <ListThumb
                    key={item.item.id}
                    navigation={navigation}
                    brand={item.item.name}
                    imageSource={item.item.image}
                    discountedPrice={item.item.price}
                    description={item.item.description}
                  />)
              }
              }}
```

This way it passes the props `category` from the Product screen onto the ProductCatalogue screen when you press on the specific tab. So now if I select tab 1 I will get only products with `category: "beverage"` and they will render in the ProductCatalogue screen, in this case, `cola` and `fanta`.

Hope I helped someone, cheers!